# Team City to deploy artifacts to external server

Tags: teamcity

I've tried taking a look on [Google](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) for how this can be done but I thought I'd post a question anyway to see what the best practice is for doing this nowadays.

We are trying to setup a Team City build to deploy to a clients environment, basically we're generating an artifacts zip file and the plan is to (somehow) deploy this to the clients UAT, Staging and Live Servers (which are password protected). When the build is run it executes a nant script.

From our network in the office we are able to remote into the UAT box, but we can only get to the Staging and Live servers whilst on the UAT box.

What is the best way of doing this? Are there any useful resources I can look at to help me move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Deployer Plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) developed by TeamCity team. It offers SMB/FTP/SSH deploy options as well as SSH Exec option.